# Jailbreak console app save photo

Tags: objective-c, jailbreak

I've created a console app for iOS using iOSOpenDev which is trying to write to the camera roll / saved photos. I've granted permission to access the photo library using entitlements (and checked that the access been granted). But I can't seem to get any form of image to save (using any examples online).

I'm using the following method to save the image:

```
UIImage *test = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(test,nil,nil,nil);
```

(when supplied) it never returns any error messages and doesn't write successfully.

I've also tried:

```
[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:.....]
```

With no better results. I think that this is a problem relating to using UIkit from a console app, rather than my implementation of the save methods?

I'm trying to run on iOS 7 & 8 ideally

Comment: Hi pleaaase if did u get a solution share it with us :)

Comment: @HDNZ nothing yet... seems like it's not possible